# Save Data to SQLite database

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, coordinates

I'm working on an application that gets the current location but my problem is that I want to store the coordinates (Latitude and Longitude) to a plist or SQLite databse or anything just I want to save the coordinates to a file !!

can someone give me a tutorial or the code to do that and thnak you

Comment: So, do you want to store it in a SQLite database OR a plist OR a file? Your question is not really a question...

Comment: it doesn't mater i wan't to save the coordinates no mater what !

Comment: Type them up in Notepad, hit ctrl-s. :) Seriously, rework your question a bit. Where are you getting the coordinates from? What device? What language or platform are you using to communicate with that device?

Comment: hhhh ok my bad :p
Im working on iphone application that return your current location and some information like the country , town and street !
so i want to store those informations either the coordinates or the (country and town and street) to an SQLite database or send them to an email .
prog Lang : objective C
IDE : xcode 4.3 

I hope my question was clear now :)

Comment: Ok. So you're asking for Objective-C code that stores those coordinates in an SQLite database? Or do yo want to know which field types to use?

Comment: @JamelNaghmouchi: The next question is very important: **What have you done so far?**

Comment: @Vapire yes i want the objC code that stores those coordinates in an SQLite database !

Comment: @MPelletier I've done the code for getting  the current location on a map ! and then converting those coordinates to meaningful information like country ,town, street, zip code.. using the CLGeocoder !

Answer (score 0):

Well... Here's an example application to get you started on how to use SQLite in iOS

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_SQLite_based_iOS_4_iPhone_Application